# How to switch custom themes in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, darkmode

I want to change themes in React.js according to condition being true or false, but when I change inserted styles in app class it only changes innerElements not the entire body.

`app.jsx`

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { dark, light } from "./comp/themes";

export default function App() {
  const isDarkMode = true;
  const DarkMode = isDarkMode ? dark : light
document.body.style.background={DarkMode};
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>hi</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`./comp/themes.jsx`

```js
export const dark = { backgroundColor: "rgb(38, 38, 38)", color: "white" };

export const light = { backgroundColor: "white", color: "black" };
```

help me to achieve to change the themes. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to assign the object's background property and not a string.
`document.body.style.background={DarkMode.backgroundColor}`

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

`app.js`

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { dark, light } from "./comp/themes";
import Toggler from "./comp/Switch";

export default function App() {
  const isDarkMode = false;
  const DarkMode = isDarkMode ? dark : light
  document.body.style.backgroundColor=DarkMode.backgroundColor;
  document.body.style.color=DarkMode.color;

  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>hi</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```